# Creating simple new parent elements with incrementing class numbers without changing the HTML

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a few elements with class names to have a number on the end that increments by 1 for each new element. E.g. `<div class='someClass1'></div>`, then `<div class='someClass2'></div>`, `<div class='someClass3'></div>`, etc...

However, I can only get the child elements to have incrementing class names, e.g. `<span class='0'>here</span>`, `<span class='1'>here</span>`, `<span class='2'>here</span>`, etc, which is done by changing the inner HTML.

How can I get the parent 'someClass' to have incrementing class numbers? I tried `newNode.classList.add("someClass + noAdded");` but returns a syntax error. Thanks for any help here - my code is as follows:

```
var testy = document.getElementById('testy'); // <div id='testy'></div>
var noAdded = 0;

function addToPage() {
        var newNode = document.createElement("div"); // <div></div>
        newNode.classList.add("someClass"); // <div class='someClass'></div>
        newNode.innerHTML = '<span class="' + noAdded + '">here</span>'; // <span class='0'>here</span>
        testy.appendChild(newNode); // <div id='testy'><span class='0'>here</span></div>
        noAdded++;
    }

addToPage();
addToPage();
addToPage();
```

Results in:

```
<div id="testy">
    <div class="someClass">
        <span class="0">here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="someClass">
        <span class="1">here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="someClass">
        <span class="2">here</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the value of the variable *noAdded* to the string *someClass*.

Change

```
newNode.classList.add("someClass");
```

To

```
newNode.classList.add("someClass"+noAdded);
```

```js
var testy = document.getElementById('testy'); // <div id='testy'></div>
var noAdded = 0;

function addToPage() {
        var newNode = document.createElement("div"); // <div></div>
        newNode.classList.add("someClass"+noAdded); // <div class='someClass'></div>
        newNode.innerHTML = '<span class="' + noAdded + '">here</span>'; // <span class='0'>here</span>
        testy.appendChild(newNode); // <div id='testy'><span class='0'>here</span></div>
        noAdded++;
    }

addToPage();
addToPage();
addToPage();
```

```css
.someClass0{color:red;}
.someClass1{color:green;}
.someClass2{color:blue;}
```

```html
<div id="testy">
</div>
```

Comment: @user8758206, do you want the class name start from 0 or 1?

Comment: thanks, that's brill. Start from 0. Turns out it's much simpler than I expected!

Comment: @user8758206, you are most welcome.....exactly....that's really simple:)